# treePanel not select a node

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I found many solution with how select the first node on a treepanel, but any more work for me.

I have a view,model,controller and json file.

I try to select the first node soon the treepanel loaded.

How can i do that.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Live example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/994

In MVC, you need to store reference for your TreePanel, and then do the same code:

```
var tree = btn.up('treepanel'), // or your saved reference here, or Ext.ComponentQuery, etc.
    root = tree.getRootNode(),
    first = root.getChildAt(0);
    first && tree.getSelectionModel().select([first]);
```

That's all!